# WebView on android zooms in

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I'm making a game for android, the game and all the files are on my server and I'm using a webView to display the game in the app

So after I got the app and everything created I noticed no matter what I change on the webView or on the server it always zooms in so the user has to zoom out In order to play

Does anybody know how I can make the canvas and background image scale to width and height

I tried

`var c = document.getElementById ('canvas');
c.width = window.innerWidth;`

This works to resize the canvas but the enemy's will still follow the path of the image

Here is a link to the game http://deathcrow.altervista.org/0android/td/index.php

If you need any of the code let me know I didn't post any cause I am on my phone

Here are links to all my coding I'm not able to put it on here due to being on my phone

http://deathcrow.altervista.org/0android/td/js/mainLoop.js

http://deathcrow.altervista.org/0android/td/js/attackerUnits.js

http://deathcrow.altervista.org/0android/td/js/towerUnits.js

http://deathcrow.altervista.org/0android/td/js/bullets.js

http://deathcrow.altervista.org/0android/td/js/mouseClick.js

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the webview not to zoom with:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);     
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Have you actually moved to coding it on a canvas instead? Am I answering your question?

Comment: What do you mean moved to coding it on your canvas?

Comment: Not 'your' canvas, 'a' canvas. Maybe I don't understand what you are doing. Are you accessing the webview's canvas? Why are you using a webview at all?

Comment: I'm using a webView to display my website, my website contins a canvas

Comment: They operable question seems to be why your 'enemies' still follow the image. Your background image? You are being too abstract. Please post some code and more details.

Comment: Added links to the files